# Ionic example app workflow

Tags: ionic-framework

I chanced upon ionic framework and find it intriguing, thus i ran the sample app "myapp". What puzzles me that upon firing index.html. It shows me a blank page while using "ionic serve" command will show a fully illustrated project.

I had some experience with phoneGap before and i could easily preview my pages that i created by running index.html.

Is there other files that are compiled with it when "ionic serve" command is ran? And what does the other files do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read here: http://www.reddit.com/r/ionic/comments/362log/how_does_ionic_serve_all_work/, it starts its own web server (like when using WAMPP or XAMPP for example).

So, I actually went to test this and it indeed is true; if you're familiar with XAMPP or WAMPP, you can start your ionic project inside the www folder of WAMPP and then you'll be able to access it via `http://localhost/myapp/www` link (without using `ionic serve` command), if you've started your ionic app with `ionic start myapp`.